# App crashed with noClassDefFound error in ArrayAdpter Android

Tags: android-studio, android-arrayadapter, noclassdeffounderror

I have a custom `listView` which contains images and text views. But in `getView` method, application got crashed.

My code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    } 
    ImageView removeWatch = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.remove_watch);
    removeWatch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("BEFOERE","on click in menuwatchadapter");
        }
    });
```

ArrayAdpter :

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuListModel> {

private Context context;
private int layout;
private List<MenuListModel> Model;

public interface ModelAction {
    public void removedModel(MenuListModel removedModel);
}

private ModelAction ModelActions;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<MenuListModel> objects, ModelAction ModelActionListener) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = resource;
    this.Model = objects;
    this.ModelActions = ModelActionListener;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }

    ImageView remove = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.remove);

    remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("TEST","CLICKED");
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

At line  `removeWatch.setOnClickListener`, application got crashed.
Can anyone tell me what can be the issue ?

**NOTE : I am using Android-Studio.**

LOGCAT :

-13 15:01:25.502  28351-28351/com.example.watch E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.watch, PID: 28351
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.watch.adapter.MenuWatchListAdapter$1
            at com.example.watch.adapter.MenuWatchListAdapter.getView(MenuWatchListAdapter.java:95)
            at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1337)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1620)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)

Comment: attach your logcat report for crashing

Comment: @Manikandan : logcat added

Comment: @Manikandan : ArrayAdapter added

Comment: No, I have not used any library.

Comment: I do not know why but i have unistalled whole android-studio and android sdk and re-install it and this is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why but i have unistalled whole android-studio and android sdk and re-install it and this is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `view = inflater.inflate(layout, null)` to

`view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Your_LAYOUT, null)` and give it a try.

Comment: layout is variable and contains same what you suggested. But not working.

Comment: attach your ArrayAdapter class

Comment: u declared the layout variable as int. Iam not sure u r inflating the layout correctly.

Comment: r u using any library in your app?